# Определить кодировку строки из $_GET[...]

Tags: php, get, utf-8, input, cp1251

Сайт к сожалению пока, что работает в 1251, возможности перевести в иную кодировку нету. Введенная строка в input передается GET запросом (без перекодировок).

В url получаю крокозяблички `?search=%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2`, получаю строку также в 1251.
Но если пользователь вводит ручками русский текст в url, то появляются проблемы.

Как это разрешить?

1. Перекодировать сообщение в UTF-8 перед отправкой в GET параметре (как)?
2. Как правильно определять кодировку из `$_GET['search']`?

Хотелось бы получить читабельный url, и возможность править строку непосредственно в урле. Конечная кодировка строки UTF-8.

Сейчас на сервере просто написано: `iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $search_string);`

Comment: Посмотрите вот сюда http://habrahabr.ru/post/107945/

Comment: @Visman Читал статью, перечитаю на досуге, но конкретного рабочего решения там к сожалению не увидел.

Answer (score 1):

Существует вот такая функция

```
/**
* Locates the first bad byte in a UTF-8 string returning it's
* byte index in the string
* PCRE Pattern to locate bad bytes in a UTF-8 string
* Comes from W3 FAQ: Multilingual Forms
* Note: modified to include full ASCII range including control chars
* @see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8
* @param string
* @return mixed integer byte index or FALSE if no bad found
* @package utf8
* @subpackage bad
*/
function utf8_bad_find($str)
{
    $UTF8_BAD =
        '([\x00-\x7F]'.                          # ASCII (including control chars)
        '|[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]'.               # Non-overlong 2-byte
        '|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]'.           # Excluding overlongs
        '|[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}'.    # Straight 3-byte
        '|\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]'.           # Excluding surrogates
        '|\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}'.        # Planes 1-3
        '|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}'.            # Planes 4-15
        '|\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}'.        # Plane 16
        '|(.{1}))';                              # Invalid byte
    $pos = 0;
    $badList = array();

    while (preg_match('/'.$UTF8_BAD.'/S', $str, $matches))
    {
        $bytes = strlen($matches[0]);

        if (isset($matches[2]))
            return $pos;

        $pos += $bytes;
        $str = substr($str,$bytes);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Она должна выдать false если на входе строка в UTF-8 или номер позиции не UTF-8 символа.
Использование:

```
$search_string = $_GET['search'];
if (utf8_bad_find($search_string) !== false)
{
   $search_string = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $search_string);
}
// $search_string  в кодировке UTF-8
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пока подожду, может кто подскажет как передавать строку в url-е читабельной.

Comment: Так современные браузеры сами переводят не латиницу из UTF-8 в читабельный текст в адресной строке. Посмотрите хотя бы на адресную строку этой страницы.